# Simple Image Capture Tool for Mac OS X that uses FireWire

Tags: macos, firewire

I have Leopard (Mac OS X 10.5) on a G4 Powerbook and a camcorder with a firewire device. It doesn't have iMovie, which is now part of the separate [iLife Suite and requires an Intel Mac](http://www.apple.com/ilife/systemrequirements.html).

Anyway, Image Capture does not recognize the firewire video feed as an image capture device. What software would give me the simplest "capture this frame from live firewire video feed to image" functionality.

Comment: Leopard is 10.5. If you have 10.4 you have Tiger

Comment: I just tried VLC and that won't do it. http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=64406&p=215126&hilit=firewire+video+capture#p215126

Comment: Mark, you are right I screwed up my cat names.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it with the [TWAIN SANE Interface](http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/). It works with a lot of scanners(including my prehistoric HP 3400), and some cameras.

Check out if you camera is listed [here](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#VIDEO).