# Capturing a firewire video feed in Leopard on a G4

Tags: macos, video-capture

I have a powerbook G4 that I loaded up with Leopard (OSX 10.5). I don't have iMovie, since the Leopard version requires an intel mac. I have a Sony Digital 8 Camcorder with firewire and usb output.   The usb output requires a special driver on windows. I don't think OSX will support it.

I wish to capture the video stream from the camera on my G4. [VLC does not support firewire capture on OSX](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=64406&p=215126&hilit=firewire+video+capture#p215126), I don't want to pay for QT professional. I'm looking for a solution. I'd prefer open source, but I'd consider freeware and inexpensive for pay options.

On a related note, [if it can capture still frames,](https://superuser.com/questions/49753/simple-image-capture-tool-for-mac-os-x-that-uses-firewire) I have a related question.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Vidi](http://www.mitzpettel.com/software/vidi.php).

> Vidi is an application that lets you
>   view and record video on your Mac
>   using any FireWire DV device. When
>   used with a Formac Studio DV, Studio
>   DV/TV or StudioTVR device, Vidi lets
>   you select the input source, change TV
>   channels and adjust picture settings.

[image: Vidi Screenshot]

Comment: Looks good, although "here is the source code, but you can't modify it" is kind of puzzling. Then again the commercial ssh program did (does) that. I won't have access to my camera until Monday. I will check then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Leopard 10.5.8 on a G5 PPC...iMovie/iDVD both work fine.

I'm not sure what type of install you did, but that could be the problem. I used the "Upgrade" option at installation, and overwrote my 10.4 OS.

Note: I used a OS X 10.5 DVD installation disk (not a bundled DVD from another Mac).